# Calling Arrayed Field to If Conditional Statement

Tags: php, wordpress, conditional-statements, statements

In the admin section:

```
$options[] = array( "name" => esc_html__("Company IDs",'press'),
"desc" => esc_html__("add Company / eSports Team, User ID to post more than one listing.",'press'),
"id" => "companyids",
"std" => "#",
"type" => "text");
```

In PHP Page:

```
<?php if ( $user->ID = (array('')) ) { ?>
```

Need to get Admin field to echo or place added IDs into PHP array. So, let's say I put a few users IDs into the field in admin like 34,64 delimited with commas.  In PHP code it will call and get admin information and place it in between ' ' after the array.

I tried this not working:

```
<?php if ( $user->ID = (array("'"<?php echo esc_html_e("Company IDs", 'press'); ?>"'")) { ?>
```

Comment: From where do you get the `34,64` ids?

Comment: You can do if (empty($user->ID)){} or if (count($user->ID) == 0){} If $user->ID is an array. You might want to var_dump the $user object to make sure your keys are right

Comment: I think OP want to get the `34,64` and insert them to array and check if the userId is one of them - something like: `in_array($user->ID, explode(",", "34,64"))`

Comment: 34,64 is just an example of ids delimited in admin panel.  The top code is for allowing admin to place 34,64 into a field.  PHP Code: is where I want the data in that esc_html are to show up.  So, if I add 34 to field PHP code will check if user id matches what is delimited in field.

Comment: Check field to see if user id match whats in the field basically.